# Overriding a hash in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am very new to ruby and I am trying to find if there's an equivalent way to doing the thing in ruby.

In yml syntax, we use a syntax similar to this way to have a default blob and then override them with specific values:

```
default:
  default:
    A:                  {read:  20, write: 10}
    B:                  {read:  30, write: 30}
    C:                  {read: 130, write: 10}

override1:
  placeholderA:
    A:             {read:  10, write: 10}

override2:
  placeHolderB:
    A:           {read:  10, write: 10}
    B:           {read: 5, write: 5}
    C:           {read: 5, write: 5}
    D:           {read: 5, write: 5}
```

I wanted to know if we can create a hash in ruby where in it will pick the values for the override if they exist, otherwise it will just pick the default value.

I am not sure if ruby merge map is an approach to this problem (since I am still new to ruby, I am exploring options).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

merge could be used:

```
options = {a:22}
my_defaults = {a:1, b:123}
my_defaults.merge(options)
> {a:22, b:123}
```

if you are using rails that also provides a reverse_merge which works the other way round and may be clearer to read intent from in some use cases

```
options = { a:2, b:321 }
my_defaults = {a:1, c:3}
options.reverse_merge(my_defaults)
> {a:2, b:321, c:3}
```

http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/reverse_merge